# Converting each and every attribute of xml into datatable column and filling its inner text as column value

Tags: c#, xml, database, linq, recursion

I am trying to start with "event" tag,which is in the event list tag of my file,its root node is marina playlist.This file contains 1024 number of event tags,now I want to to make the attributes as datatable column and fill the column value with its inner text.
For ex-
event type will be a column and its value will be Comment,event enabled will be a datatable column and its value will be true.Now its child node properties is null so we will leave this,and iterate to the next child event which is again null,but its child comment have value so it will be converted into datatable,then schedule startType is also nt null it have attribute so schedule will become column and filled with value Sequential.
Now coming forward to next event tag,type,enabled,tiermarker,uid are already in datatable so we will iterate to the next child nodes and do the same thing,and if any new tag is found which has attribute like mediaStream som then it will become column,segment type,and then markup orderNo will become column,markup name will also become column and its value will be the innertext..
This is my file.I am trying for past 3 days but not getting solution.If done through recursion then it will be great help.

```
<marinaPlaylist version="3.1">
<properties>
 </properties>
 <eventList>
<event type="Comment" enabled="true" timerMarker="false" uid="4473">
<properties>
 <event>
  <comment>11/21/2016 10:21:48:22 - User 'Browse 2' Loaded List 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/الخميس   17 -11 -2016 - Copy.mpl'.</comment>
 </event>
<schedule startType="Sequential"/>
  </properties>
 </event>

<event type="PrimaryVideo" enabled="true" timerMarker="false" uid="4480">
   <properties>
    <mediaStream som="00:00:00:20">
    <segment type="Markup">
  <markup orderNo="1" name="TxSegments"/>
  </segment>
  <video jobType="Play"/>
<allocation type="ListStream">
<listStream type="Fixed" listStreamNo="0"/>
</allocation>
  </mediaStream>
 <schedule endOffset="00:02:51:00" endType="Duration" startType="Sequential" startOffset="2017-05-03T06:00:00:00"/>
 <media mediaType="Video" mediaName="RJ-000001"/>
<event title="السلام الملكي "/>
<switch rate="Fast" transition="Cut">
<source type="Auto">
<auto type="MediaStream"/>
</source>
  <backupSource type="Auto">
  <auto type="MediaStream"/>
</backupSource>
<destination type="Auto">
  <auto type="PGM"/>
 </destination>
 <backupDestination type="Auto">
 <auto type="PGM"/>
</backupDestination>
</switch>
</properties>
 </event>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.  It is just a start and not sure how to handle the element values and the attribute values.   Let me know if I can modify code as needed

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Events(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Events
    {
        public static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public static int idCount = 0;

        public Events() { }
        public Events(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            XElement eventList = doc.Descendants("eventList").FirstOrDefault();

            string[] columnNames = eventList.Descendants().Select(x => (string)x.Name.LocalName).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Parent ID", typeof(int));

            foreach (string columName in columnNames)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(columName, typeof(string));
            }

            int rootId = idCount;
            RecursiveParse(eventList, rootId);
        }
        public void RecursiveParse(XElement parent, int parentID)
        {
            foreach(XElement child in parent.Elements())
            {
                int childId = idCount++;
                DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
                row["Parent ID"] = parentID;
                row["ID"] = childId;
                string name = child.Name.LocalName;
                string value = (string)child;
                row[name] = value;
                if (child.HasElements)
                {
                    RecursiveParse(child, childId);
                }


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is populating the gridview in this way:
id,     parentid,    allocation,     auto,    backupdestination,   
backupsource,    block,    comment,    destination,    event,    fixed,    liststream,    logical,    markup,    media,    mediastream,    properties,    schedule,    segment,    source,    switch,    video.
These rae the column names which I have listed here and the data inside them is also null,only comment,event and properties column are filled.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jdweng for your quick reply and helping in solving the query.However I got the solution for the above query.
If you can modify the code to make it short then it will helpful because it is taking time in loading the form and populating the gridview.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillData();
    }
    public void fillColumns(XElement rootValue)
    {
    docu = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);          
        if (rootValue != null)
        {
            Queue<XElement> queue = new Queue<XElement>(rootValue.Elements());

            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                XElement xelement = queue.Dequeue();
                if (xelement.HasAttributes)
                {
                    foreach (XAttribute attribute in xelement.Attributes())
                    {
                        string sColName = xelement.Name.ToString().Trim() + "" + attribute.Name.ToString().Trim();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sColName) && !dt.Columns.Contains(sColName))
                        {
                            DataColumn dtCol = new DataColumn();
                            dtCol.ColumnName = sColName;
                            dt.Columns.Add(dtCol);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!xelement.HasElements && xelement.Value != null)
                {
                    string sColName = xelement.Name.ToString().Trim();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sColName) && !dt.Columns.Contains(sColName))
                    {
                        DataColumn dtCol = new DataColumn();
                        dtCol.ColumnName = sColName;
                        dt.Columns.Add(dtCol);
                    }
                }
                if (xelement.HasElements)
                {
                    fillColumns(xelement);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void fillRows(XElement rootValue, XElement actualValue)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rootValue != null)
            {
                Queue<XElement> queue = new Queue<XElement>(rootValue.Elements());

                while (queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    XElement xelement = queue.Dequeue();
                    if (xelement.Parent == actualValue)
                    {
                        if (dtRow != null)
                            dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
                        dtRow = dt.NewRow();
                    }
                    if (xelement.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        foreach (XAttribute xattribute in xelement.Attributes())
                        {
                            string sColName = xelement.Name.ToString() + "" + xattribute.Name.ToString();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sColName) && dt.Columns.Contains(sColName))
                            {
                                dtRow[sColName] = xattribute.Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!xelement.HasElements && xelement.Value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xelement.Value))
                    {
                        string sColName = xelement.Name.ToString().Trim();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sColName) && dt.Columns.Contains(sColName))
                        {
                            dtRow[sColName] = xelement.Value;
                        }
                    }
                    if (xelement.HasElements)
                    {
                        fillRows(xelement, actualValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
    public void fillData()
    {
        docu = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
        XElement xElement = docu.XPathSelectElement("//eventList");
        dt = new DataTable();
        fillColumns(xElement);
        fillRows(xElement, xElement);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```